# how to create a stackset to deploy the s3 gateway endpoint in all AWS accounts

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

how to create a stackset to deploy the s3 gateway endpoint in all AWS accounts.

I want to deploy the s3 gateway endpoint in all AWS accounts.

To deploy an S3 Gateway Endpoint in multiple AWS accounts using AWS CloudFormation StackSets, StackSets allow you to deploy a CloudFormation stack across multiple accounts and regions.